# How to retrieve the parent-item-id in MS graph

Tags: api, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to use [this](https:////https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) query using the MS office api, it looks like this:

`POST /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-item-id}/children`

I can not seem to find the parent-item-id of the parent folder, and it only work when I use `root` as id. I tried to find the ids of all folders using:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site_id}/drive/root/children`

This returns a list of all folders in root, along with their ids. However, when I replace `root` by a folder id I get no results, only `Resource not found for the segment`.

How should I go about finding the folder id? I already tried the method above and looking at the share link of the folder. Both do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) source it is possible to locate folder in your onedrive using the following syntax:

`GET /drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children`

This finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a GET call on /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/ and find the parentID of all the items that you intentded to find

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).